# remove page header of Wordpress Escapade theme

Tags: wordpress

Please tell me how to remove or reduce the size of the header of the wordpress theme

https://wpnux.godaddy.com/?theme=escapade&header_image=https%3A%2F%2Fisteam.wsimg.com%2Fstock%2Fef2c8ef864af75bb4e22e186f28c6cb9574f44106d815e1b09acce4d8f3748ec

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the template well you can try to hide it in the CSS:

```
#masthead{
display:none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

I would add the !important to override any styles in regular CSS.

If you want to make it smaller this code will adjust the height:

```
.blog .site-header, .page .site-header, .archive .site-header, .single .site-header {
    padding: 120px 0; // Adjust the 120px here
    position: relative;
}
```